# Manually plotting some particular graphs

Tags: analysis, functions, graphing-functions

How to plot graphs like these manually:

1) $f(x)=\ln(1+x^2)$

2) $f(x)=\frac8{2+x^2}$

3) $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1+\tan^{2}x}}+\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+\cot^{2}x}}$

I have no idea how to plot the nature of these functions on pen and paper without using any software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1 see the asymptotic $f_1(x) \sim \ln(x^2) = 2\ln |x|$ and note that $1+x^2 \ge 1$ so $f_1(x) \ge 0$ and opens up like $\ln$ to both sides (resembles a smooth bucket)

Similarly, the shape of $f_2$ is like the shape of $\frac1{1+x^2}$, somewhat like a bell with its only maximum at $0$ with value $4$.

For 3 just try some algebraic manipulations: $\sqrt{1+\tan^2 x} = |\sec x| \sqrt{\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x} = |\sec x|$ and analogously $\sqrt{1+\cot^2 x} = |\csc x|$.
This shows $f_3(x) = \sin x|\cos x| + |\sin x|\cos x$. Now using cases you'll get a piecewise function wich is $\pm\sin 2x$ or $0$ depending on the interval of $x$.

Generally it's always good to

- simplify the function as much as possible
- do a curve discussion (roots, extrema, inflection points)
- compare to known graphs

Comment: Sorry your third function graph is wrong.Check it on wolfram alpha.Its not graph of sin 2x.

Comment: http://www4a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP23791d2gb9174dfgaied0000432c2e38bc7571b7?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=51&w=345.&h=153.&cdf=RangeControl

Comment: @SanchayanDutta Thanks for checking. I fixed it now.

Comment: You're welcome.And thank you too :-)